# I am trying to build the table like structure using React Indiana Drag Scroll package,but after reaching certain point the first column also scroll

Tags: css, reactjs, scroll, bootstrap-5.1

I am trying to build the table like structure using React Indiana Drag Scroll package,but after reaching certain point the first column also scroll.I used React Indiana Drag Scroll package to scroll the table horizontally and vertically using mouse.i used flex property with position sticky.

## html

```
<div
    class="tabular--header-fixed tabular--side-col-fixed ">
    <div class="scroll-container scroll-horizontal tjs-table-overflow indiana-scroll-container">
        <div class="tabular__header d-md-flex">
            <div class="inner-element">
                <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-between w-100">
                    <h6 class="me-10 mb-0 text-truncate cursor-pointer">col1</h6>
                    <div class="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="tabular__body">
            <div class="inner-section d-md-flex">
                <div class="inner-element align-items-start p-md-15 mb-20 mb-md-0" style="z-index: 97;">
                    <div class="flex-grow-1">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-start">
                            <div class="me-15"><input type="checkbox" id="custom-0" class="form-check-input"></div>
                            <div><a class="text-dark text-hover--primary fw-semibold text-capitalize fs-14 me-5"
                                    href="/admin/leads/leads-list/64a50aa0ab6fd22b981de353">ching chong</a></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the css code for the html

## css

```
.tabular {
    
    &--header-fixed {
        @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
            .tabular__header {
                position: sticky;
                top: 0;
                z-index: 99;
            }
        }
    }

    &--side-col-fixed {
        @media screen and (min-width: 767px) {
            .scroll-horizontal {

                .tabular__header .inner-element:first-child,
                .tabular__body .inner-element:first-child {
                    position: sticky;
                    left: 0;
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```